# Ubuntu 16.04 / Samba Network Share Disconnecting during Windows Server Backup

Tags: server, 16.04, backup, samba

We are having a problem with failing backups on our Windows Server 2012 R2.

The backup makes it 60 - 100MB into backup before the backup fails.

The backup location is a VHD made with vhdtool on a samba network share.

The samba share disconnects from the network and the VHD becomes unavailable and the backup fails.

The Windows server is a Ubuntu virtual and the Samba Share is based on the same Host Server.

Is there any known issues caused by writing onto a Samba Network Share on Ubuntu 16.04?

We have also tried without the VHD, just making the backup in a folder on the share. It still disconnects.

We have many setups like this in the field but they are all 14.04 or older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered that it was an existing network issue.
Our way to get around this was to not use the network at all. 
Instead we created an .img file with qemu-img create and used virsh attach-disk to link it to the VM. 
Then it was just a matter of attaching the disk from the server side using powershell.
Mount it as a drive letter and then sharing using windows instead.

Just thought I would document that in case anyone was having the same issue.